# Dynamically creating projection of fields with nested List fields in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, projection

I'm using Spring-boot 1.5.9 and I'm trying to dynamically create projections using Hibernate and JPA 2.0 but I'm failing for some specific cases.

Consider the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity")
public class Entity {
   
   @Id
   @Column(name = "entity_id", nullable = false)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "first_field", nullable = false)
   private String firstField;

   @Column(name = "second_field", nullable = false)
   private String secondField;
   
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<NestedField> nestedField;

   //getters and setters
}
```

And also the NestedField Class;

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "nested_field")
public class NestedField {
   
   @Id
   @Column(name = "nested_field_id", nullable = false)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "first_field", nullable = false)
   private String firstField;
   
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", referencedColumnName = "entity", nullable = false)
   @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
   @JsonBackReference
   private Entity entity;

   //getters and setters
}
```

The code bellow is the code I'm using to dynamically create projections of the class Entity by Strings that represent the list of fields (ex.: "field1,field2,etc"):

```
// projection String is expected to be "field1,field2,field3,...,fieldN"
private List<T> fetchProjectionData(String projections, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Class<T> entityClass) {
    
    CriteriaQuery<Object> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object.class);
    Root<T> root = query.from(entityClass);
    
    List<Selection<Object>> projection =  getProjectionFields(projections, root);
    query.multiselect(projection.toArray(new Selection[]{}));
    
    try {
        List<Object> result = (List<Object>) entityManager.createQuery(query)
                .setMaxResults(100)
                .setFirstResult(0)
                .getResultList();
        
        return mapResultSet(result, projection, entityClass);    
  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error.");
        return null;
    }
}

public List<Selection<Object>> getProjectionFields(String projections, Root<T> root) {
    try {
        String[] projectionFields = projections.split(",");
        List<Selection<Object>> projection = new ArrayList<>();
        
        if (!projectionFields.isEmpty()) {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < projectionFields.length; i++) {
                projection.add(root.get(projectionFields[i]));
            }
        }
        
        return projection;
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error.");
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

// mapResultSet map the result fetched into instances of the parametrized class
```

I expected to be able to project fields of the Class Entity (no matter what field, simple or nested, or Collection).

Unfortunately, the code above works only when String projection parameter is composed only with non List fields or only the List value.

Example:

```
String projection = "id,firstField"; //OK
Srting projection = "nestedField"; //OK
String projection = "firstField,nestedField"; //Fails in method .getResultList(), JPA builds a query with syntax error
```

The funny thing is, if nestedFields was not a List, but a single entity, like bellow, the above code would have worked:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "nested_field_id", referencedColumnName = "nested_field_id")
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
private NestedField nestedField; // if nestedField was this way, the code would have worked
```

And this is the exception hibernate JPA throws:

```
2018-03-18 22:50:46.535 DEBUG 20990 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select . as col_0_0_, entity0_.first_field as col_1_0_, nestedfiel1_.nested_field_id as nested_f1_2_, nestedfiel1_.first_field as first_fi2_2_, nestedfiel1_.entity_id as entity_i3_2_ from entity entity0_ inner join nested_field nestedfiel1_ on entity0_.entity_id=nestedfiel1_.entity_id limit ?
2018-03-18 22:50:46.545  WARN 20990 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2018-03-18 22:50:46.545 ERROR 20990 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
```

It appears as hibernate JPA replaces my projection with empty string, resulting in a single lost dot ".", which of course, causes an error, although the query is almost correct (if you remove the lost dot ".").

I notice that `root.get(projectionFields[i])` return a class of type `PluralAttributePath` when the field is a nested List, while it returns a `SingleAttributePath` when field is a simple field. I wonder if this has anything to do with my problem.

Does anyone have any clue to solving this?

Have I done anything wrong building my query?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: JPQL BNF in the JPA spec says clearly enough that you cannot "SELECT" any multi-valued fields. Criteria simply makes JPQL available via an API. You cannot select multi-valued fields. Not "funny" at all. Sticks to the JPA spec